# SQL error when trying to insert

Tags: mysql, sql

Been trying to make a huge SQL (around 200 queries) in order to fast insert the data into the database however for some reason i'm getting  SQL error but not sure what is causing it.

The Error:

> **SQL Error (1064):** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `'6', '1', '21', '4128', '8388608', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0',` at line 8

Here is a part of my code:

```
SET @ID = 2710601;
SET @DID = 420591;

INSERT INTO item_template (entry, class, subclass, name, displayid, Quality, BuyCount, InventoryType, Flags, FlagsExtra, maxcount, ContainerSlots, BuyPrice, SellPrice, dmg_type1, dmg_type2, dmg_min1, dmg_min2, dmg_max1, dmg_max2, delay, ammo_type, RangedModRange, itemset, bonding, block, MaxDurability, sheath, holy_res, frost_res, fire_res, shadow_res, nature_res, arcane_res, socketColor_1, socketColor_2, socketColor_3, socketContent_1, socketContent_2, socketContent_3, socketBonus, GemProperties, spellid_1, spellid_2, spellid_3, spellid_4, spellid_5, spelltrigger_1, spelltrigger_2, spelltrigger_3, spelltrigger_4, spelltrigger_5, spellcharges_1, spellcharges_2, spellcharges_3, spellcharges_4, spellcharges_5, spellppmRate_1, spellppmRate_2, spellppmRate_3, spellppmRate_4, spellppmRate_5, spellcooldown_1, spellcooldown_2, spellcooldown_3, spellcooldown_4, spellcooldown_5, spellcategory_1, spellcategory_2, spellcategory_3, spellcategory_4, spellcategory_5, spellcategorycooldown_1, spellcategorycooldown_2, spellcategorycooldown_3, spellcategorycooldown_4, spellcategorycooldown_5, startquest, material, randomproperty, randomsuffix, area, map, disenchantid, pagetext, languageid, pagematerial, foodtype, lockid, holidayid, BagFamily, ArmorDamageModifier, duration, ItemLimitCategory, minMoneyLoot, maxMoneyLoot, flagscustom, TotemCategory, AllowableRace, AllowableClass, ItemLevel, RequiredLevel, RequiredSkill, RequiredSkillRank, requiredspell, requiredhonorrank, RequiredCityRank, RequiredReputationFaction, RequiredReputationRank, RequiredDisenchantSkill, StatsCount, stat_type1, stat_type2, stat_type3, stat_type4, stat_type5, stat_type6, stat_type7, stat_type8, stat_type9, stat_type10, stat_value1, stat_value2, stat_value3, stat_value4, stat_value5, stat_value6, stat_value7, stat_value8, stat_value9, stat_value10, ScalingStatDistribution, ScalingStatValue) VALUES
(@ID+13, '2', '10', 'Artifact Weapon', @DID+13, '6', '1', '21', '4128', '8388608', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1000', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '-1', '-1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '-1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0')
```

[My full SQL you could find on PasteBin.](https://pastebin.com/2SV0X2U2)

No idea what is causing it as the '6' after is perfectly fine (maybe something to do with the `@Defines`? I did try with them being `:= (VALUE)` but had the same outcome.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please show code as formatted text, not as image, not as link, certainly not as non-clickable link

Comment: @HoneyBadger what do you mean? what part?

Comment: And what `@DID+3` returns? You should really consider reducing your example to [mcve]. While in the process compare this specific line with others to see what might cause problems.

Comment: @MarekVitek since @DID+0 is 420591 then @DID+3 should equal 420594.

Comment: This looks like appallingly poor design. See normalisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And have you tried to reduce it to version where is only line for which you are getting error.

```
SET @ID = 2710601;
SET @DID = 420591;

INSERT INTO item_template (entry, class, subclass, name, displayid, Quality, BuyCount, InventoryType, Flags, FlagsExtra, maxcount, ContainerSlots, BuyPrice, SellPrice, dmg_type1, dmg_type2, dmg_min1, dmg_min2, dmg_max1, dmg_max2, delay, ammo_type, RangedModRange, itemset, bonding, block, MaxDurability, sheath, holy_res, frost_res, fire_res, shadow_res, nature_res, arcane_res, socketColor_1, socketColor_2, socketColor_3, socketContent_1, socketContent_2, socketContent_3, socketBonus, GemProperties, spellid_1, spellid_2, spellid_3, spellid_4, spellid_5, spelltrigger_1, spelltrigger_2, spelltrigger_3, spelltrigger_4, spelltrigger_5, spellcharges_1, spellcharges_2, spellcharges_3, spellcharges_4, spellcharges_5, spellppmRate_1, spellppmRate_2, spellppmRate_3, spellppmRate_4, spellppmRate_5, spellcooldown_1, spellcooldown_2, spellcooldown_3, spellcooldown_4, spellcooldown_5, spellcategory_1, spellcategory_2, spellcategory_3, spellcategory_4, spellcategory_5, spellcategorycooldown_1, spellcategorycooldown_2, spellcategorycooldown_3, spellcategorycooldown_4, spellcategorycooldown_5, startquest, material, randomproperty, randomsuffix, area, map, disenchantid, pagetext, languageid, pagematerial, foodtype, lockid, holidayid, BagFamily, ArmorDamageModifier, duration, ItemLimitCategory, minMoneyLoot, maxMoneyLoot, flagscustom, TotemCategory, AllowableRace, AllowableClass, ItemLevel, RequiredLevel, RequiredSkill, RequiredSkillRank, requiredspell, requiredhonorrank, RequiredCityRank, RequiredReputationFaction, RequiredReputationRank, RequiredDisenchantSkill, StatsCount, stat_type1, stat_type2, stat_type3, stat_type4, stat_type5, stat_type6, stat_type7, stat_type8, stat_type9, stat_type10, stat_value1, stat_value2, stat_value3, stat_value4, stat_value5, stat_value6, stat_value7, stat_value8, stat_value9, stat_value10, ScalingStatDistribution, ScalingStatValue) VALUES
(@ID+7, '2', '10', 'Artifact Weapon', @DID+7  '6', '1', '21', '4128', '8388608', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1000', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '-1', '-1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '-1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0');
```

**EDIT** : You are missing coma between @DID+7 and '6':

```
@DID+7  '6'
```

**EDIT2**: How can you solve this problem by yourself? Use [bisection method](https://www.nics.tennessee.edu/faq/darter-how-do-i-use-code-bisection-method-find-bug) to isolate data in question.

Comment: I have no idea on what parts will error in the SQL query, as from what I could tell it should have worked and incremented ID & DID correctly,

Comment: I don't know. I just copied minimal code from your example with data on line 8 only.  You should try it yourself. And if this code works, then you should try to remove data from the original query until it will work, then you will know where real error is. Sometimes error messages can be misleading. You didn't provide table structure, so nobody is able to reproduce your error. And without that it is really hard to debug.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/nzYBaMYV - That is the table structure (create code)

Comment: And please consider marking your question as solved, so others trying to help would know, there is no need to revisit this question.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)